# Application Error: ClassNotFoundException - TTT.jar - Java Applet

Tags: java, class

I made a basic Tic-Tac-Toe game and I want it to be played on my website. Currently it is not up but just on my computer. So I am testing it. I used an applet code:

```
<applet code="TTT.jar" width="500" height="500">
  <APPLET ARCHIVE="TTT.jar" CODE="Main.Main.class" WIDTH=500 HEIGHT=500>
  </APPLET>
</applet>
```

I extracted the code to check if I had the path right and it looks perfectly right to me.

[image]

[Here Is The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbR2G.png) Im Getting.

[image]

Comment: Do you have `package Main;` in Main.java ?

Comment: That's not a good package name to begin with, anyway.

Comment: http://www.imagebam.com/image/946284342096239

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't it be...?

```
<applet code="Main.Main.class" archive="TTT.jar"
   width="500" height="500"></applet>
```

http://www.simplehtmlguide.com/javaapplets.php

Comment: Im Getting A New Error Now: Runtime Exception - java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException